# Partitioning a list by recursion (Programming Paradigms via Mathematica (A First Course))

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I am working through the course *Programming Paradigms via Mathematica*. One of the homework exercises for the section *Recursion I:  Passing the Buck* is as follows:

> Use recursion to partition a list:  "recurPartition[L_List,k_Integer]"
>   should return the same thing as "Partition[L,k]".  Of course, don't
>   use "Partition[]".

The following additional limitations are also applied:

> First, use of a repetition function ("Map[]", "MapThread[]", "Nest[]",
>   "NestList[]", "Fold[]", "FoldList[]", "Table[]", "Apply[]", and so on,
>   being our "adverbs") will generally disqualify a method as purely
>   recursive, for the repetition is accomplished externally from the
>   nested function calls.  Also, repetition accomplished with a loop
>   structure, such as a "While[]", a "Do[]", or some other repetition
>   command, is explicitly forbidden.

Here was my code, following many edits:

```
Clear[recurPartition]
recurPartition[{}, k_] := {}
recurPartition[L_List, k_Integer] := 
 If[Length[L] >= k, {Take[L, k], recurPartition[Drop[L, k], k]}]
recurPartition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2]
```

Which produced the following output:

> {{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {{5, 6}, {}}}}

By contrast `Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2]` would produce:

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

I can't figure out what I should have done differently and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were pretty close.

Here's what I have sticking to your basic construct.

```
Clear[recurPartition]
recurPartition[l_List, k_Integer] := 
  If[Length[l] >= k, Join[{Take[l, k]}, recurPartition[Drop[l, k], k]]]

recurPartition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2]
```

> `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`

Your condition `Length[l] >= k` is your terminating condition.

To use a function downvalue as the terminating condition, you can use:

```
recurPartition[l_List, k_Integer] /; k > Length@l := {}
recurPartition[l_List, k_Integer] := Join[{Take[l, k]}, recurPartition[Drop[l, k], k]]
```

And here's a one-line, J.M.-inspired version:

```
recurPartition[l_List, k_Integer?Positive, remainderQ_:False] := 
  If[Length@l >= k, {l~Take~k}~Join~recurPartition[l~Drop~k, k, remainderQ],
  If[remainderQ, {l}, {}]]
```

Comment: One-liner: `recurPartition[L_List, k_Integer?Positive] /; Mod[Length[L], k] == 0 := If[Length[L] >= k, Join[{Take[L, k]}, recurPartition[Drop[L, k], k]], {}]`

Comment: @0x4A4D HA. I knew you'd swing by with a slick one.

Comment: I do feel that `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` might be a bit too advanced for this application, tho.

Comment: @0x4A4D, Yeah, you're probably right. I added a version inspired by your comment that adds a remainder option.

Comment: Nice filigree! Too bad I cannot upvote again.

Comment: @kale, Thank You for showing me an example that sticks close to the original, I can now see where I made my mistake. I did want to ask if there is a reason for using `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` as opposed to `{}`, I ran the code both ways and got the same results.

Comment: @Clif, Technically, your terminating condition `recurPartition[{}, k_] := {}` is never used because of the condition in the `If` statement. In your example, you don't seem to be interested in "remainder" elements (when the length of the list isn't a multiple of the partition size), so the `If` statement works fine. (see edit).

Comment: @kale, Thank You again, I ran the edited code and also ran my code w/o the `If` statement and they do seem to work the same until you get to "remainder" elements, which I don't think were accounted for in the exercise, as `Partition` seems to just drop them itself.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because it does what the homework exercise asked, and is understandable to me. However, I want to make sure that any future reader will look at Leonid Shifrin's answer as it "outperforms" (IHMO) the `Partition` statement as of version 9.0.1

Comment: @Clif, Thanks for the accept. Leonid always has great solutions (even though he did use `Fold` & `Map` :) ). As far as your comment on Leonid's solution, the last version I gave you has the option to keep the "remainder" items, although it still won't outperform on a speed basis.

Comment: @Clif Just a side note: built-in `Partition` will be much faster than any top-level code we might come up with, particularly on numerical (packed) arrays. So, in this case, this is just an instructive exercise. But there are cases where top-level code can be quite fast even compared to built-ins, although they are admittedly less common.

Comment: @Clif The more important thing here is that most posted solutions are not tail-recursive, which limits them severely, because it is quite easy to overflow the stack. In Mathematica, this will lead to a silent kernel crash, with all the possible unwanted consequences such as loss of work and data. All versions above could be made tail-recursive if the result gets accumulated in a separate argument to the `recurPartition` function.

Comment: @kale, are you talking about the solution that includes `remainderQ` ?

Comment: @Clif, That's the one.

Answer (score 10):

As I attempted to explain [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25474#25474), recursion on lists is more involved in Mathematica than it may seem, in part because lists are implemented as arrays (rather than linked lists) in Mathematica.

What I will suggest here is again a solution based on linked lists. It may be a bit harder to understand initially, but arguably it is closer to the true spirit of recursion. It will also be faster than many of the posted answers, and be tail-recursive [in the Mathematica sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica/4627671#4627671).

Here is the code

```
ClearAll[ll];
SetAttributes[ll, HoldAllComplete];
toLinkedList[l_List] := Fold[ll[#2, #1] &, ll[], Reverse@l]
```

The main function will use two linked lists for accumulation of intermediate results, and one linked list for the input data. Partitioned chunks will be collected into linked lists with the head `List`, while the elements inside individual chunks will be collected into linked lists with head `ll`.

```
ClearAll[partitionLL];
partitionLL[l_List, k_] := 
   Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, 
     partitionLL[toLinkedList[l], k, {}, k - 1]
   ];
partitionLL[ll[], k_, accum_, n_] := 
   Map[List @@ Flatten[#, Infinity, ll] &, Flatten[accum]];
partitionLL[ll[head_, tail_], k_, accum_, n_] /; n == k - 1 :=
   partitionLL[tail, k, {accum, ll[ll[], head]}, 0];
partitionLL[ll[head_, tail_], k_, {accum_, current_ll}, n_] :=
   partitionLL[tail, k, {accum, ll[current, head]}, n + 1];
```

The two-argument form of the function converts the initial list into a linked list. After that, the real recursive part has 4 arguments. The recursion stops when the input list is an empty list `ll[]` - it then converts the list of accumulated results back to a normal list. The other two definitions implement the general recursive step. The first one creates a new partitioned chunk, the last one fills the existing partitioned chunk with a current head of the input list.

Here is a simple example:

```
partitionLL[Range[10], 2]

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}}  *)
```

Here is a more serious test:

```
partitionLL[Range[20000], 2]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.118164, Null} *)
```

Note that recursive solutions not using linked lists will generally be slower for large lists because of sub-list copying on every iteration. Note also that one needs to take a special care to make the solution tail-recursive, to make it of any practical use (in the case of functions like `Partition`, at least).

Comment: The links to your previous answers are very informative, and the results of your code are indeed impressive, as they outdo (to my way of thinking) `Partition` in that where `Partition[Range[3],2]` yields {{1, 2}} your code produces {{1,2},{3}} which to me is a superior result, however I will have to say that the course question gave the qualifier, "the same thing as `Partition[L,k]`", and your code, while superior, doesn't. As far as your serious test of time, my code set off so many error messages and ran so much slower that I really don't want to compare. :-)

Comment: @Clif Thanks. Re: `Partition` - there is an extended syntax for `Partition` which would not dismiss the left-over too. And one can also modify my code above to go the other way around and dismiss the left-over - this should not be hard. Re: speed comparison - I meant not just your code but most of the posted solutions that were using plain lists.

Comment: is `Partition[Range[21], 2, 2, 1, {}]` an example of what you are talking about? I had missed that while looking over what `Partition` does, thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @Clif Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 7):

```
part[l_List, n_] := Module[{p},
  p[{f : Repeated[_, {n}], rest___}] := Sequence[{f}, p[{rest}]];
  p[{Repeated[_, n-1]}] := Sequence[];
  {p[l]}
  ]
```

but probably something along the lines of halirutan's solution is more appropriate

```
part2[l_List, n_] := part2[l, n, {}];
part2[l_List, n_, res_]/;Length@l<n := res;
part2[l_, n_, curr_] := part2[l~Drop~n, n, Append[curr, l~Take~n]]
```

Comment: What happened if you try `part[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2]`?

Comment: Hey @Silvia! I'm afraid to try. But I assumed the truncation and argument checking weren't part of the OP's doubts

Comment: I'm just +1 and saying :D Maybe `p[f : Repeated[_, n - 1]] := Sequence[]`?

Comment: There we go @Silvia. Don't try a negative `n` ;D

Comment: Well `Partition` itself doesn't handle negative `n` as well :)

Comment: Thank You for showing me a way to code this using `Repeated`, that is a command that I had not encountered, and it seems useful. The second code is going to take some time for me to understand, hopefully I'll get there.

Comment: @Clif, I hoped it would be an educational example. But it shouldn't be very efficient. In fact, it would make the Leonids die a little inside

Answer (score 6):

Here an implementation which emulates the `Take` by recursion too

```
rp[l_, k_?Positive] := rp[l, {}, k, k] /; Length[l] >= k;
rp[l1_, l2_, k_, iter_] := rp[Rest[l1], Append[l2, First[l1]], k, iter - 1];
rp[l1_, l2_, k_, 0] := Join[{l2}, rp[l1, k]];
rp[__] := {};
```

The trick is that you have two different recursions through two different call patterns although the functions name is `rp` in all cases. I hope it works, it's pretty late here.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works very well, and I can see where adding the `?Positive` restriction to k_ is good programing procedure.